# Angular. how to compile directive inside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have

```
<div id="content"><div>
```

I want to insert my directive. I did

```
html = $compile('<test></test>')($scope);
$("#content").html(html);
```

My directive:

```
app.directive("test", function ($compile, $route) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Templates/test.html",
        controller: function ($scope, $location) {},
        controllerAs: "page"
    };
});
```

"/Templates/test.html":

```
  ... some code ...
<category></category>
```

directives test and category upload some data from server.
For some reasons category works, but test doesn't. 
Anybody knows why?
Thanks

Comment: First why do you want to inject your <test> like this in your #content ? If you want to change the content accordingly to the current path/state of your application use ngRoute (native) or ui-router (3rd party library). You should never use $/augular.element in other things than directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could be required to recompile your directive. Add following code at the end of link function:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Some useful info here: [$complie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand how it use it my case.
$compile($compile('<test></test>')($scope).contents())($scope) - ?;